# How to open a pdf in a new tab in flask

Tags: python, flask

Hey guys just doing a flask assignment for college to make a simple web application and im trying to open a pdf file in a new tab from my index page. I can open the file in the current tab no problem but cant wrap my head around opening it in a new tab. My code is attached below. Thanks for any time put into answering this.

I have tried using redirect and webbrowser.open_new_tab but might not have been using them correctly.

Dan

```
@app.get("/my_cv")
def my_cv():
    workingdir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
    filepath = workingdir + '/static/files/'
    return send_from_directory(filepath, 'DanielTurnerCV.pdf')
```

Comment: You can't do what you want with server-side code. Server-side code returns the pdf to the client, doesn't know/care what the client will do. At the client side (html, javascript) you can open the pdf in a new tab/window.

Comment: Thank you for answering is it possible to open the index page again before returning the send from directory ? So the cv will still open in the current tab but the index page will open itself again

Comment: You need to change the html code to open the PDF in a new tab. Something like this: `<a href="/my_cv" target="_blank">My CV</a>`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help